# fast sorting using .net 3.5 framework

Tags: .net, vb.net, sorting

In a scientific application I'm writing (vb.net) I use a huge collection of object stored in a tree structure. Every object exposes a LastAccessed property (datetime) that stores the last time the node was accessed by the algorithm.

I need to find a fast way to find the N least accessed objects in the structure.

I'm using an algorithm like this (pseudo-code)

```
dim Olist as new list (of myobject)
....
array.sort(Olist,address of compareByDataReverse)
for index=0 to N-1
   dosomething(Olist.item(index))
end
```

I'm sure there is a better way to do that because the list is normally huge ( consisting of more than 10^6 objects).

Thanks
Pierluigi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in best case your code will perform with O(nlogn). You should begin with `dim Olist as new list (of myobject)` then take a LinkedList and go over your collection and add values to your list keeping it sorted. This will be O(n*m)

Comment: That's called insertion sort and it's O(n^2) - which is worse than O(nlogn) - so it's likely to be slower on datasets that large.

Comment: please read carefully. There are two values n - size of ENTIRE collection and m - size of list he want to have. and m is much smaller then n. then reread my answer and your comment.

Comment: Andrey has explained better than me the situation N, size of the collection is HUGE while M, size of the elements is a short list...in my application I might expect N=10^4m

Comment: Why not just use a sorted list/array and keep it sorted. Inserts will then take O(log(n)). Retrieval of the first n O(1).

It all depends on the number of inserts compared to the number of selects. If there are a lot more selects, keep it sorted.

Comment: @pierusch - Are you sure you mean 10^4m?

Comment: @Carra there no sorted arrays with insertion of O(log(n)). they are nlogn, because you first find the value (logn) then insert (n)

Comment: @gauterin......excuse me..... N~10^3M just for an example in my last running test (N=100000 m=150) but it's not a constant...

Comment: As suggested by Andrey I used a linkedList while keeping it stored... using N=100000 and m=100:
1) using my "old" approach 267ms
2) using a linked list approach 23ms
well.... thaks to everybody......

Answer (score 2):

You mention that you use a tree structure yet you show us a list. If you use a list you can indeed sort it (O(l log(l)) and then take the last n elements in O(1). Or just iterate it and get your last n elements in (O(l)).

You however work with a tree view. You didn't mention how your tree is implemented. You can create a binary search tree with as key your LastAccessed date. Searching for your first N elements can then also be done very fast.

Alternatively you could keep an index. Just create a tree view with as key the LastAccessed date. Inserting or removing an item in your original list should also update your index. You can then quickly retrieve a link to your items based on their date. At the cost of slower inserts/removals.

Comment: you are righ :) what i wrote is a bit confusing becouse I'm not that goog in writing in english! the list a mentioned is just a list of reference to the leaves of the tree.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [**Selection sort**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) then after **N iterations first N elements will be in sorted** order.

NOTE:But I am not sure if this solves your problem completely.

Comment: not completely...I mean i'm sure the array.sort(...) function is really well implemented...I just think there is a better way to find the N least accessed elements inside the list WITHOUT sorting the entire list of objects... anyway thanks for your reply :)

Comment: :) so you can stop Selection Sort after N steps!

Comment: +1 avoids sorting all the data (but may be slower if the number of items to find is very large).

Comment: I don't know why but what I think is this should be fine as long as `N^2 < (TotalNumberOfItems)/2`. What do you say?